# how to avoid this error in mysql while updating a record?

Tags: mysql

I have table dapartment_dup where I want to update a record when I execute the query it gives me an error

My query is

```
update department_dup 
set dept_name = null
where dept_no = 'd010';
```

and the error is

> 21:17:21  update department_dup  set dept_name = null where dept_no =
>   'd010'    Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried
>   to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column.  To disable
>   safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and
>   reconnect.    0.000 sec

in the error message, it gives me the path but I can't understand where to reconnect?

Comment: I think the error message is pretty clear.  What don't you understand?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff  I can't understand it. sorry, I am a beginner in SQL? if the question is stupid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your IDE  (probaly  mysql Workbench ) You have `safe mode` enabled .. this mean that you can perform update or delet only using in where condition  a column that is the primary key for the row .. In your case dept_no is not the primary key  ..

SO if you want use the update code  in you question  you could disable the safe mode in you mysql Workbench

or add  a conditio that involve you primary key column
assuming your primary key column is name your_key_col   add  AND your_key_col <>

```
update department_dup 
set dept_name = null
where dept_no = 'd010'
AND   your_key_col<>0;
```